# how to convert start date parameter to microsecond in custom query?

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I try to use custom query in Google Looker Studio as the data source. and here is the custom SQL to fetch data from my BigQuery

```
WITH analytics_data AS (
  SELECT user_pseudo_id, 
         UNIX_MICROS(TIMESTAMP("2023-03-10 00:00:00", "+7:00")) AS start_day,
         3600*1000*1000*24*7 AS one_week_micros
  FROM `project.analytics_297774888.events_*`
  WHERE _table_suffix BETWEEN @DS_START_DATE AND @DS_END_DATE
)
```

as you can see I enable date range parameters, so I use `@DS_START_DATE` and `@DS_END_DATE` . my problem is in this one line

```
UNIX_MICROS(TIMESTAMP("2023-03-10 00:00:00", "+7:00")) AS start_day
```

currently it is hardcoded string (`"2023-03-10 00:00:00"`). I want to replace the date string with `@DS_START_DATE`. If I change the code to be like one below, I will have error

```
UNIX_MICROS(TIMESTAMP(@DS_START_DATE, "+7:00")) AS start_day
```

I am trying to get Unix Microsecond (number of microseconds since 1970-01-01) of date `@DS_START_DATE` at 00:00:00 in timezone UTC + 7

how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `@DS_START_DATE` and `@DS_END_DATE` has a shape of `YYYYmmdd`, you can parse it using [`PARSE_TIMESTAMP`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#parse_timestamp) like below along with timezone.

```sql
UNIX_MICROS(PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m%d', @DS_START_DATE, '+7:00'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 WITH analytics_data AS (
  SELECT user_pseudo_id, 
         UNIX_MICROS(TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(@DS_START_DATE, " 00:00:00"), "+7:00")) AS start_day,
         3600*1000*1000*24*7 AS one_week_micros
  FROM `project.analytics_297774888.events_*`
  WHERE _table_suffix BETWEEN @DS_START_DATE AND @DS_END_DATE
)
```

Comment: unfortunately I have error like this: Sorry, we encountered an error and were unable to complete your request. Error ID: 773f942b